# Set Catalog visibility hidden woo-commerce

Tags: wordpress

How to set Catalog visibility hidden in woo-commerce WordPress programmatically?

Like its mentioned here :

https://docs.woothemes.com/document/catalog-visibility-options/

But i can't find any hook or hack, that how to do it in PHP.

Comment: When you edit product, the Publish block has option for Catalog Visibility ... but ... reading both answers below from Daniel Ramirez and Andy Tschiersch I have confirmed that there seems to be BOTH of those settings in the database. However even when taxonomy is set to exclude-from-search & exclude-from-catalog and post_meta is set to hidden, the product will still show up in search. It succesfully gets hidden from the catalog but does not get hidden from search. I have reported this as a bug to WooCommerce (v3.9.1) as I can not figure why else the item would not be hidden from the search.

Answer (score 22):

I have tried doing this for some days, and there is nothing about it online so I read the woocommerce documentation and discovered that in woocommerce 3.x.x the visibility is a taxonomy called "product_visibility".

To achieve that you should set taxonomy terms, for example:

```
//Set product hidden: 
$terms = array( 'exclude-from-catalog', 'exclude-from-search' );
wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, $terms, 'product_visibility' );

//Set product visible in catalog:
$terms = 'exclude-from-search';
wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, $terms, 'product_visibility' );

//Set product visible in search:
$terms = 'exclude-from-catalog';
wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, $terms, 'product_visibility' );
```

All possible taxonomy terms:

```
"exclude-from-catalog"
"exclude-from-search"
"featured"
"outofstock"
```

Comment: How do you then set a product back to normal catalog visibility after doing this?

Comment: To make the catalog visibility normal again you can pass an empty array as $terms when calling the wp_set_object_terms function.

Answer (score 7):

The visibility is set in the custom field `_visibility`. You can change it with [`update_post_meta()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta):

```
update_post_meta( $product_id, '_visibility', '_visibility_hidden' );
```

**Possible values:**

- `visible` (Catalog & Search)
- `catalog` (Catalog only)
- `search` (Search only)
- `hidden` (nowhere)

Comment: @jameshwartlopez no, this isn't valid as of Woocommerce 3, visibility is set in taxonamy as of v3. See https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/2.6.x-to-3.0.0-Developer-Migration-Notes#product-visibility-is-taxonomy-based-instead-of-meta-based

Comment: @Zubair1 appreciate the link.