# Set catalog visibility in WooCommerce

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

Do you know if there is a method or code in MySql to change the catalog visibility of product in WooCommerce? I have tried to set _visibility in the table postmeta, but it doesn't work.

Comment: What u exactly needed? What you fid with code?

Comment: What you want to achieve? do you want to hide all the product from catalog?

Comment: I found it through another post. You would use PHP and use the methods from WordPress.
Click this: 
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36522439/set-catalog-visibility-hidden-woo-commerce)